# how to read the following data from excel using cucumber-java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, cucumber

---

- Heading

[image]

How to get the username and password from excel using cucumber

```
package com.qa.excel;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelReader{
//  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException   {
//ExcelReader reader=new ExcelReader();
//  reader.readExcelData();
//  }
    public Object[][] readExcelData() throws IOException
    {
        String Filepath="E:\\Old\\ExtentReports\\ExcelFiles\\login.xlsx";
        File file=new File(Filepath);
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file);
        XSSFWorkbook book=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet=book.getSheetAt(0);
        Object[][] data=new Object[sheet.getLastRowNum()][2]; 
        for(int i=1;i<=sheet.getLastRowNum();i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<sheet.getRow(i).getLastCellNum();j++)
            {
                Cell cell=sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j);
                switch(cell.getCellType()) {
                
                case STRING :
                {
                    data[i-1][j]=cell.getStringCellValue();
                }
                case NUMERIC:
                {
                    data[i-1][j]=cell.getStringCellValue();
                }
                default :
                {
                    data[i-1][j]=cell.getStringCellValue();
                }
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<data[i].length;j++)
            {
                System.out.println(data[i][j]);
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

I'm able to get username and password from excel using java but, I'm not understanding how to get the data in step definition in `sendkeys`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use the Test Parameters when using Cucumber, you use the Scenario outlines. So, when you have:

```gherkin
Scenario Outline: Login As User
When I log in as '<user>'
  Examples:
  | user          |
  | xyz@gmail.com |
```

You would have your test step definition handle that by using an Excel reader.

```java
@When("^I log in as \"([^\"]*)\")
public void WhenILogInAsUser(user) {
  // import Excel file into file reader
  // get pass for {user}
  // perform login action(s)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But i didn't get you can you please provide me one sample

Comment: You can check out the [answer to how to Read/Write an Excel file on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516144/how-to-read-and-write-excel-file).